Seeking UX Recommendations with Future Feature Expansion in Mind - Date/Time/Repeat/Duration selection for a Todo app
I’m facing a dilemma in my UX design for a Todo app. Should I prioritize making the flow more efficient with fewer steps to complete a common task?
Or, should I focus on a cleaner, less cluttered UI?
Currently, I have three UX approaches in mind to achieve the following goal:
Goal: Select tomorrow, 6 pm.
UX A


Step 1 : Tap on date row
Step 2 : Tap on tomorrow
Step 3 : Tap on time row
Step 4 : Tap on 6pm
Step 5 : Tap on Save


UX B


Step 1 : Tap on tomorrow
Step 2 : Tap on Time on Date/Time segment control
Step 3 : Tap on 6pm
Step 4 : Tap on Save


UX C


Step 1 : Tap on tomorrow
Step 3 : Tap on 6pm
Step 4 : Tap on Save


The current iOS flow to create an Event on the Calendar app is the better way. Not sure why we are trying to recreate the wheel here.
Concept A: is counter intuitive. The user is going back a screen to save the form. Switching screens disconnects the user from the overall flow.
Concept B: has wrong use of component. Segmented controls do not mean they are in sequence. Here we have a sequence to the flow – date > time > note.
Concept C: is the best out of the three. But there is no need to hide the time picker. We can use accordion to show the time contextually right below the button.

Yes, +1. I would add: Concept A suffers from poor usage of screen space. Only the top most rows are used (hardest to reach with the thumb). To All: It is counter-intuitive to have the "save" function pop up a comment input. The UX flow should be: Provide the functionality to use the App, do not force or require the user to use the App your way. "Save" means "done". The screen before means "here you can setup your date/time/info/color/image/whatever properties". The comment input thing should be integrated there.
